# iPhone Safari browser font displayed issue

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts, safari, text-rendering

[image: iPhone 6 Plus screenshot]

I use the font "Sofia Pro" in my project. Within the display of the same phone (iPhone6 Plus), the font is displayed perfectly  in  Chrome and Mozillar, however appeared to be cracked in Safari. In iPhone 5S Safari, it was not as bad but blurry. It rendered fine on iPhone 4 Safari.
I had tried:
{-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;} and
{text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;}
However, there's no luck.
Does anyone has an idea what this issue origins from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements are animated with transform: translateY(value);
Changed translateY(value) to translate3d(value,value,value) and the rendering is smooth again.